# Erro JPA com Wildfly - No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Projeto

Tags: java, jpa, wildfly

Olá!

Estou criando uma aplicação de teste bem simples, utilizando JPA, Wildfly como servidor de aplicação e Oracle Database 11g Express Edition como banco de dados.

O intuito da classe Teste é executar uma consulta de Pessoas. Sempre que executo a classe Teste, aparece o erro **"No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Projeto".**

Quando troco o servidor para o Tomcat 8 ou Glassfish funciona normalmente, só não consigo fazer funcionar no Wildfly. Agradeceria muito se alguém me ajudasse.

Segue abaixo maiores informações.

**Stacke Trace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at br.com.pessoa.dao.PessoaDAO.getPessoas(PessoaDAO.java:13)
at br.com.pessoa.util.Teste.main(Teste.java:13)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Projeto
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at br.com.pessoa.util.JPAUtil.<clinit>(JPAUtil.java:9)
... 2 more
```

**Classe Pessoa:**

```
package br.com.pessoa.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Pessoa.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Pessoa p")
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="PESSOA_PESSOAID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SEQ_PESSOA")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PESSOA_PESSOAID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="PESSOA_ID")
    private long pessoaId;

    @Column(name="CPF_CNPJ")
    private String cpfCnpj;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="DATA_CADASTRO")
    private Date dataCadastro;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="DATA_NASCIMENTO")
    private Date dataNascimento;

    private String email;

    private String endereco;

    private String nome;

    private String sexo;

    private String telefone;

    public Pessoa() {
    }

    public long getPessoaId() {
        return pessoaId;
    }

    public void setPessoaId(long pessoaId) {
        this.pessoaId = pessoaId;
    }

    public String getCpfCnpj() {
        return cpfCnpj;
    }

    public void setCpfCnpj(String cpfCnpj) {
        this.cpfCnpj = cpfCnpj;
    }

    public Date getDataCadastro() {
        return dataCadastro;
    }

    public void setDataCadastro(Date dataCadastro) {
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
    }

    public Date getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }

    public void setDataNascimento(Date dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }        

}
```

**Classe PessoaDAO:**

```
package br.com.pessoa.dao;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;    
import br.com.pessoa.model.Pessoa;
import br.com.pessoa.util.JPAUtil;

public class PessoaDAO {

    public List<Pessoa> getPessoas(){
        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        return em.createNamedQuery("Pessoa.findAll",Pessoa.class).getResultList();
    }    

}
```

**Classe JPAUtil:**

```
package br.com.pessoa.util;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public final class JPAUtil {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Projeto");

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

**Classe Teste (método Main):**

```
package br.com.pessoa.util;

import java.util.List;    
import br.com.pessoa.dao.PessoaDAO;
import br.com.pessoa.model.Pessoa;

public class Teste {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        PessoaDAO pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();        
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = pessoaDAO.getPessoas();    
    }    
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Projeto" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>br.com.pessoa.model.Pessoa</class>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx"/>

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>  
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>            

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Você está em um container JEE, pode usar `JTA` e recuperar uma EM do contexto CDI. Mesmo assim, se quer usar como colocou, adicione `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` no seu `persistence.xml`, pode ser logo acima da declaração da `class`, e veja se funciona. Outra coisa é o que está no *classpath* quando executa o `main`. Veja se há de fato um *provider* JPA, além tentar alterar o `transaction-type`, removendo-o.

Comment: Fiz as alterações que você sugeriu e mesmo assim continua não funcionando.
Alterando o projeto para utilizar um JTA DataSource e injetando a EntityManager, a classe Teste continua dando erro, desta vez me retornando um java.lang.NullPointerException. A EntityManager está nula, não está sendo injetada. O mais estranho é que no Glassfish esse mesmo código funciona normalmente, só no Wildfly 8.2 que não

Answer (score 1):

Para criar o datasource manualmente, altera para transaction-type="JTA", exclui as linhas do persistence.xml:

```
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx"/>
```

Adiciona essas configurações dentro do standalone.xml do wildfly, dentro da tag 'datasources':

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/nomeProjetoDS" pool-name="nomeProjetoDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>usuario</user-name>
                        <password>senha</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

Dentro da tag 'drivers', incluir:

```
<driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
                        <xa-datasource-class> oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource </xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
```

Agora tem que incluir seu driver dentro de um módulo no wildfly. No seu caso fica num diretório como "wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/main".

Esse link pode ajudar a configurar o driver: [exemplo-datasource-oracle-wildfly](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Example_Oracle_XA_Datsource1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Para usar JTA você deve criar um Data Source.

Acesse localhost:9990 e crie um.

você também pode usar o data source de exemplo que é criado automaticamente.